# How to add to an array in Javascript by inserting a number and moving the numbers after to the right

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to insert a value into an array. I am not changing the size of the array. All I want to do is insert a value and then move all numbers after the insertion to the right using this algorighm:

1. Go to the last element in the array n = (length-1)
2. If it is not the passed index (n > index), set it's value to the value of the previous element A(n) = A(n-1)
3. If it is the passed index (n = index), set the value to the passed value A(n) = value and exit
4. Move left one element n = n-1
5. Repeat steps 2, 3, and 4

How do I do this?  Also, I can't use any built-in array functions. Here is an example of my Javascript code:

```
var array = [];
for(var i=1; i<=1000; i++) {
array.push(Math.round(Math.random()*100));
}

function InsertIntoArray(array,index,number){
var numCount = 0
var move = 0 ;
for(var move = array.length - 1; move > index; move--)
{
  if (move > index)
  {
      array[i] = array[i-1];
      numCount ++;
  }
  else (move == index)
  {
      array[index] = number;
      numCount++;
      break;
  }

}
console.log(move);
console.log(numCount);
console.log(array);
}
console.log(array);
InsertIntoArray(array, 1, 11);
```

Comment: With that approach, won't you lose the last item in the array? Or is that the point.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek He said he doesn't want to increase the size of the array. So something has to go.

Comment: `array[i]` should be `array[move]`, etc.

Comment: Spencer:  That would be the point...so basically the last item would be dropped...ex: [1,2,3,4,5] after inserting 11 [1,11,2,3,4]

Comment: Your code looks almost correct, just there's no `i` variable in your loop, it should be `array[move] = array[move-1]`.

Comment: Also, you don't put a condition after `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close but doing a log more than required. Hopefully the comments are sufficient:

```js
// Just use simple test cases initially
var array = [0,1,2,3];

// The original function had some unused and pointless variables,
// they're removed
function insertIntoArray(array, index, value){
  
  // Don't allow index to be greater than length - 1
  if (index > array.length - 1) return;
  
  // Loop until the required index is reached, shifting
  // values to the next higher index
  for(var move = array.length - 1; move > index; move--) {
    array[move] = array[move - 1];
  }
  
  // Must now have reached required index and have shifted
  // values, so just insert
  array[index] = value;
}

// Original array
document.write(array + '<br>');

// Do insert
insertIntoArray(array, 2, 15);

// Modified array
document.write(array);
```

Note that you can have sparse arrays, the above will create new elements in such arrays so they aren't sparse any more. Also, for large arrays, it will be quite inefficient, Barmar's *splice* + *slice* answer is likely better in that regard, though it does change *length* along the way.

Comment: I think this is what I am trying to do.  We are also learning Big O notation and this is a way, I think, to learn about efficiency.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, again.  I need a counter to count the number of operations.  How do I add that back in?

Comment: I guess just inside the for loop and increment it on each loop.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your loop was that you were using `array[i] = array[i-1]`, but the index variable in your loop was `move`, not `i`.

You don't need to do the `if` inside the loop. Just insert the new element when the loop is done. You also had a syntax error in the `else` -- you don't put a test after `else`, it's automatically the opposite of the `if`.

```js
function InsertIntoArray(array, index, number) {
  // Move all the elements after index up by 1
  for (var move = array.length - 1; move > index; move--) {
    array[move] = array[move - 1];
  }
  // Insert the new element
  array[index] = number;
}

var array = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
  array.push(i);
}
document.getElementById("before").textContent = JSON.stringify(array);
InsertIntoArray(array, 1, 11);
document.getElementById("results").textContent = JSON.stringify(array);
```

```html
<b>Before:</b> 
<div id="before"></div>
<b>After:</b> 
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: I am not supposed to use .splice...have to use the algorithm listed in the question.

Comment: Your question should mention that you're not allowed to use any of the built-in array functions. All the answers are using them.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the arrays into a left and right array at the `index`, add the item onto the left array, and remove the last item from the right one. Then combine the two arrays:

```
function InsertIntoArray(array,index,number){
    var leftArray = array.slice(0, index);
    var rightArray = array.slice(index, array.length - 1);
    leftArray.push(number);
    return leftArray.concat(rightArray);
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cq082hc8/). Note using `return` is to change the value of the array given other than the local `array` value. Simply changin `array` in the function will not change the global `array` variable.